# JQuery direct child x or y

Tags: jquery

How can I write a selector to have a direct child x or y, for example I have this selector at this moment

```
$("div.menu-vertical > ul.root > li.static > a")
```

In this case I get an `<a>` but I would like get `<a>` or `<span>` as direct child?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) to get the direct child and pass the selector inside it as a `multiple selector`,

```
$("div.menu-vertical > ul.root > li.static").children("a,span");
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `or` selector, so you need to write two selectors, which you can combine in a single object using `,`:

```
$("div.menu-vertical > ul.root > li.static > a, div.menu-vertical > ul.root > li.static > span")
```